# where certificate will be stored in system when using makecert command line

Tags: wcf, security, ssl

```
echo off
set SERVER_NAME=localhost
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Server cert setup starting
echo for server: %SERVER_NAME%
echo making server cert
makecert.exe -sr LocalMachine -ss MY -a sha1 -n CN=%SERVER_NAME% -sky exchange -pe
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In which folder of the Microsoft Management Console (MMC) shall I put the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

- `sr` parameter = location. In your case LocalMachine
- `ss` parameter = store. In your case My which means Personal in Certificate snap-in

So you will find your certificate when you open Certificate snap-in for Local computer and check Personal store.